# How to create a perfumed scent box

Tags: wood, woodworking, fiber-crafts, preparation

I am looking to create different scented wooden boxes for a business idea I have in mind. However, not having any experience in scented objects I wanted to know what would be the best way to go about this. The box I have measures 14 x 9cm x 4cm and is made of pinewood. My initial plan is to add the scent to synthetic wool, wait for it to completely dry and then insert this into the wooden box and seal it shut. However, I don't know how well this will work or the required amount of scent to achieve this. I don't want to spend a lot of money on fragrances I may or may not need.

To conclude, Would like to know if anyone knows how much ml of fragrance would be appropriate to use on the fibre for each box and what would be the most effective and long-lasting method of keeping the scent. I am happy for a scent that lasts for more then a week and have contemplated adding holes in the box to achieve this.

Secondly, what would be the cheapest way to achieve this for different scents. Should I purchase the scents or attempt to make them myself?

If anyone has come across doing something similar and has their own idea of what works best would appreciate very much.

I've attached a picture of the scented fibre In the box. [image]

Comment: Please concentrate on one question alone and ask any further questions later in new posts. Also, I'm not sure I understand your intention. The box you show clearly has a magnetic closure, so it's supposed to be opened. Do you not want your boxes to open? How tightly sealed should they be? and what are your plans for shelf life vs. active use? If the scent is strong (evaporates quickly) then it may be faded before a customer buys it, but if it last longer (evaporates slower) then it's less intense.

Comment: I will be using super glue to seal the boxes shut for the product i have in mind. Adding the scented fiber in the box will be carried out prior to shipment to avoid the scent fading. I am mainly pondering if i should buy seperate scents or make them myself. I have never made fragrance before so wanted to know how difficult it might be. Also, wanted to know how much scent should roughly be used for the fibre shown.

Comment: Hi Artsywolf, thanks for the update. Please [edit] the added information into your question. Also, if whether or not making it yourself is the main question, please focus on that. It's of course also possible to ask multiple questions on this site :)